# How do I make separate endpoint calls in angular universal SSR and SPA without leaking the SSR endpoint?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have a server that I am using to host my Angular Universal Express-Server, and it happens to be the same server that hosts my API.

Currently, I have a factory that builds my API service in the module, and sets the base URL path via environment file swapping

```
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment"
...
export function apiConfigFactory(): apiConfiguration {
    const params: apiConfigurationParameters = {
        basePath: environment.apiEndpoint,
    }
    return new apiConfiguration(params)
}
```

When using angular as a regular SPA, I simply tell it to make requests to the right endpoint through cloudflare by using the environment file swapping method above.

When using SSR, I would like the requests that get made to directly call my server instead of having to route to Cloudflare and back. I believe I can determine the basePath using `isPlatformBrowser`, and switch back and forth between `environment.apiEndpoint` and `environment.localApiEndpoint`, however this leaks the endpoint that I am using locally. Its not major, but I would like to be able to avoid this if possible.

Is there a way to make separate endpoint calls in angular universal SSR and SPA without leaking the SSR's endpoint in the environment file?

Answer (score 0):

This is at least somewhat achievable by using separate environment files for rendering server side and for the the single page application side.

Using `...server.configuration.<configName>.fileReplacements` much like `...build.configuration.<configName>.fileReplacements` but instead of replacing your environment file with the normal per-environment file, you can use a different environment file that has separate configurations for the api endpoints etc.

This simplifies code that requires hitting the endpoints and I don't think it will leak the endpoint itself as there should be no trace of that data in the SPA or leaked during page rendering, however I have yet to fully confirm this